# Android: proper intent-filter to indicate my application can open a filetype?

Tags: android, android-manifest, android-intent

I am trying to configure my manifest file to indicate my application can open PDF files.  The below configuration works, but it gives some funny behavior with the emulator:

1. When the "view" action is present, my application is not started on install (when I run from Eclipse, the application gets installed on the emulator, but it does not start automatically).
2. When `application/pdf` is present, after running from eclipse the application doesn't show up in my emulator's application menu.

(I don't see either of these issues if my only intents are "main" and "launcher")

```
 <intent-filter>
     <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
     <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
     <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
     <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
     <data android:mimeType="application/pdf" /> 
 </intent-filter>
```

**EDIT**:  Okay, I was a little confused about intents.  The solution to my above issues is to have 2 different intent-filters, as shown below.

However, I do have a second question.  Android successfully launches my app for PDF files, but when it launches `onCreate(bundle)` is called and not `startActivity(Intent)`.  How should I get the intent data?

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <data android:mimeType="application/pdf" /> 
</intent-filter>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your Activity, you can use `getIntent()` to get the intent used to start it.

Answer (score 0):

`startIntent()` is not a callback. Its a method for **you** to call in order to launch **another** intent.

When your Activity is launched, you will get your `onStart()` (and `onCreate`, just before that), called, and from there you call `getIntent()` to re